# Django Axios GET Request not allowed

Tags: django, reactjs, get, axios

I'm trying to make a simple, unauthorized request from axios to Django, but it's not working, with result "401 unauthorized". The thing is, this request doesn't require that user is signed in, so I don't know exactly what's the error.

my django view:

```
@api_view()
@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])
def main_enterprise_name(request):
    return Response({'name': Enterprise.objects.get(main_instance=True).name})
```

The Django URL:

```
path('api/enterprise/main/', views.main_enterprise_name, name='main_name'),
```

Axios config:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "attcsrf"
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFATTTOKEN"
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
});

api.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    const token = getToken();

    if (token){
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer '.concat(String(token));
    }
    
    return config;
});
```

When I make this request in browser, it works just fine, but with axios this fails with unauthorized.

Comment: Did you mean 401?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, going to correct it